# What Condition Can Concrete Be In And Be Recycled?

Tags: concrete, basement, recycling

I have a basement slab that I'm going to be breaking up and sending to a recycler. Here's what I would like to avoid:

- The concrete being rejected at the site of recycling
- The concrete causing some problems with the recycler's facilities

Both are admittedly unlikely, but I'm a worrier. In my basement I have carpet pads that I will be removing to access the slab, and those pads were attached to the concrete with what I assume was construction adhesive several decades ago. I'm wondering how clean I need to get the concrete to be able to get it accepted for recycling.

I asked the recycling facility this question, but didn't get an answer. Anyone know?

Comment: it doesn't have to be pure, they mainly don't want mud and debris...

Comment: @dandavis Great, so as long as I don't have big chunks of carpet pad on it, I should be OK? There's a portion of my slab that's coated with a really tough type of material that is putting up a big fight against my scraper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fine, as long as the amount of debris is low.  A bit of carpet glue, no problem.  Huge chunks of carpet, or mud, no good.  Of course you can ask the recycling company for a contamination rate, but pretty much if it looks clean, it's good to go.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_recycling

Comment: Never would have thought of wikipedia for this. That page actually answered another question I was wondering about as well - is there a problem in recycling concrete with lead-based paint? It looks like there isn't.